# Reducing mapreduce output files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written the code to generate the word and its corresponding frequency of occurrence for task1-input1.txt excluding the stop words in the stopwords.txt

```
public class TopKCommonWords {

public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    Set<String> stopwords = new HashSet<String>();
    private static final String STOP_WORD_PATH = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\CS4225\\TopKCommonWords\\input\\stopwords.txt";

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) {
        try {
            Path path = new Path(STOP_WORD_PATH);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fs.open(path)));
            String word = null;
            while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stopwords.add(word);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            if (stopwords.contains(word.toString()))
                continue;
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "counter1");
    job.setJarByClass(TopKCommonWords.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[3]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

}

This are my arguments.
[image]

I understand that by changing

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

from 0 to 1, I can get the words and its frequency of occurrence in  task1-input2.txt.

For example in my output of occurrences:

```
task1-input1:      task1-input2:

coffee 3           coffee 2
happy 10           good 3
good 6             sweet 5
```

How can i compare these 2 output and only return the common and the ones with the least frequency?
The expected result should be:

```
coffee 2
good 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to sum words from all files, you don't need to combine output files, instead, you can use `addInputPath` multiple times to read multiple files using MultipleInputs class

Alternatively, you should be able to pass `input` folder as an argument to read all files within it.

---

If you want to find the word with minimum count *per file*, you'll need a second reducer

You already have output location as a variable

```
Path output1 = new Path(args[3];
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output1));
```

So create another job that reads that location

But you might be able to use only one job if you use a Combiner to do the word count, and using the filename as your key